# Compactness of the set of terms in a convergent (sub)net and its limit

Tags: general-topology, limits, compactness, nets

In a Hausdorff topological space, let net $(x_d)_{d \in D}$ converge to $x$. The set 
$$
(\cup_{d \in D} \{x_d\}) \cup \{x\}
$$
consisting of its terms and the limit need not be compact: in $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology, the net of rationals in $[0,1]$ with the standard order converges to $1$, yet $[0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ is not compact.

But is there always a subnet of $(x_d)_{d \in D}$ whose terms, together with limit $x$, form a compact set?

I came across this claim in a recent paper, but don't see how to prove this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try this:  $X = [0,\omega_1]$ a set of ordinals in the order topology, where $\omega_1$ is the least uncountable ordinal.  Let $D \subseteq X$ be all of the non-limit ordinals.  It is directed in its usual order, the net $x_d = d$ converges to $\omega_1$.  Now try to find your subnet.

Comment: That’s a problem only if you use what Aarnes & Andenæs, *On Nets and Filter*, Math. Scand. 31 (1972), 285-292, call $M$-subnets. If you use their nicer definition, $\omega_1$ with its usual order is a subnet of your net, and it works just fine.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott so you are saying the statement is incorrect for the usual definition of subnet (the classical one), but only (possibly) for the AA-subnet? Do you see a proof for AA-subnets?

Comment: @Henno: That is what I was saying, but I had a mental hiccup and misremembered their definition; $\omega_1$ is **not** a subnet in either sense, and GEdgar’s example does show that the result is false on either interpretation of *subnet*.

Comment: I admit that I never worked with ordinals before, so I had to check up on some definitions. I have an idea for the proof. Does it make sense? (1) Every subnet contains uncountably many different terms; (2) Each non-limit ordinal is an isolated point: (3) Using (1), I find an open set $U$ containing $\omega_1$ which fails to cover infinitely many of these isolated points. Then $U$ and the `small' neighborhoods making the non-limit ordinals isolated constitute a cover without a finite subcover.

Comment: OK! You proved that it ($\omega_1$ together with the set of values of the subnet) is not compact.  That works.  I was thinking it may be easier to prove instead that it is not closed: it contains a countable increasing sequence, whose limit (a limit ordinal) is not in the set.

Comment: Ah, that seems easier. Let me check whether I understood the details of that right: the limit (=sup/union) of the sequence exists since it is bounded from above and consequently the set of upper bounds has a least element by the well-ordering property. As the limit of a countable sequence, it is less than $\omega_1$, and it can't be  a non-limit ordinal, since these are isolated. Correct, or am I missing something?